# How to detect a response which does not have an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Complete newbie question :

When I query to database using API, I sometimes get a response which contains no objects.

With the code below no alerts are raised at all.

I need a method to detect this type of empty response - `jQuery.isEmptyObject` does not work.

```
$.get("http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
{ soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"},
function(datani) {

alert(datani);

if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(datani)) {
alert("empty");

}
```

Comment: you get "" alerted, or blank ?

Comment: _"I sometimes get a response which contains no object"_ , _"I need a method to detect this type of empty response"_ What do you mean by "empty" ? Is first `alert()` called ?

Comment: With the code above no alert box appears at all.

Answer (score 0):

use done event to identify.

```
 <script>
    $.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confusing no response as being an empty `object`.

Something like:

```
var myObj = {};
```

would be considered an empty object that `isEmptyObject()` would return true for but an empty string (no response) would not

Try changing:

```
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(datani)) {
```

To

```
if(!datani) {
```

Comment: You need to debug the actual request and make sure it is even succeeding. Inspect it in browser dev tools network

Answer (score 0):

> With the code above no alert box appears at all.

The first `alert()` should be called; whether response is object or not.

You can add error handling to ajax request using `.fail()` to alert `textStatus`, `errorThrown` or property of `jqxhr` object.

Note, also `js` at Question is missing closing `})` at `$.get()` .

```
$.get("http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay",
  { soc: soc, coarse: "false", filters:"region:12"},
  function(datani) {
    alert(datani);
}).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown)
})
```

Comment: @Bizzy Is `"coarse"` spelled correctly ? Is `soc` defined ? What is `soc` ? Is `alert()` at `.fail()` called using `js` at post ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. All the variable names are correct. This code functions correctly when the API returns some data and my app works fine. But sometimes my query asks for non-existent data and then this problem occurs.

Comment: _"But sometimes my query asks for non-existent data and then this problem occurs."_ What do you mean by "this problem occurs" ? `alert()` should be called whether response is object or not; successful or returns an error

Comment: @Bizzy What is expected result when _"query asks for non-existent data"_ ? What is response when this occurs ?

Comment: Thanks again. The API is a database of possible jobs and their pay. The "soc" part of the query is the job name (eg. dentist) If I submit a job name for which the database has data it will return the pay. However, if I submit a job name but the database does not have data this problem occurs. What happens is that if I submit a successful query I will get the pay, put it into a variable called nipay and print it. However if my next query is not successful, the value from the previous query is mysteriously retained in the nipay variable, in spite of code which assigns the new value.

Comment: @Bizzy _"However if my next query is not successful, the value from the previous query is mysteriously retained in the nipay variable"_ Note `nipay` is not included or described at original Question ? Is response from server success or error if database does not return "pay" ? Can you include portion of `js` which sets, resets `nipay` variable ?

Comment: Thanks @guest271314. I think I will start a new thread to include the entire code so that the context is more clear.

Comment: @Bizzy See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Bizzy You should be able to update the variable at both success and error of ajax call